# NSButton use setFont not working

Tags: cocoa, macos

Please help me. I want to change font size for the text of NSButton.

```
[myButon setFont:[[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20]]];
```

But it didn't work.

I have another question. 
How to rotate a NSButton?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To rotate the button you may call

```
    [button setFrameRotation:90];
```

That will rotate the button 90° anticlockwise.

Comment: This method has the following problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7278852/animated-rotation-of-nsview-contents

Answer (score 1):

**Button Font**

Your line contains a syntax error, one pair of brackets should be removed.
The following line works correctly:

```
[theButton setFont:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20]];
```

Make sure the `IBOutlet` is connected properly to the `NSButton`.

**Rotate Button**

You can simply create an .png image with the vertical button title.
Use 13px Lucida Grande to make it look native.

[image]

Next add the image to a Bevel Button.
The final result looks pretty good.
[image]